# How do I quantize a three-band color image into a color image using logarithmic function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, quantization

The logarithmic function is I' =C*ln (I+1) (for each band), where I is the original value (0~255), I' is the quantized value,  and C is a constant to scale I'  into (0~255), and ln is the natural logarithm.

I tried this so far:

```
C1 = double(C1);
C = 0;
I = (C*log(1+C1));
image(I);
figure;
```

And the result is a black image.

Comment: What have you tried? See [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `C=0` then multiplied by `C`. Instead, compute `C` by considering the maximum value the resulting image and making sure it scales to `1`.

```
I = log(C1+1);
C = 1/max(I(:));
I = C*I;
image(I);
```